# Efficient Way of Getting URL Redirect from Persistent URLs

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, redirect

I have a dataset that, in part, has a URL field indicating the location of a resource. Some URLs are persistent (e.g. handles and DOIs) and thus, need to be resolved to their original URL. I am primarily working with Python and the solution that seems to work, thus far, involves using the `Requests HTTP library`.

```
import requests
var_output_url = requests.get("http://hdl.handle.net/10179/619")
var_output_url.url
```

While this solution works, it is quite slow as I have to loop through ~4,000 files, each with around 2,000 URLs. Is there a more efficient way of resolving the URL redirects?

I tested my current solution on one batch and it took almost 5 minutes; at this rate, it will take me a couple of days (13 days) to process all the batches [...] I know, it will not necessarily be that long and I can run them in parallel

Comment: if you need the content of each url then trying to optimize network time from url redirection in request is the wrong approach.

Comment: I actually do not need the content. I need to resolve to the original URL because I am wanting to determine the domain the content is from.

Comment: ok then my answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `HEAD` instead of `GET` should give you only headers and not the resource body, which in your example is html page. If you only need resolving url redirections, it would result in quite less time on data transfer over the network. Use parameter `allow_redirects=True` to allow redirection.

```
var_output_url = requests.head("http://hdl.handle.net/10179/619", allow_redirects=True)
var_output_url.url
>>> 'https://mro.massey.ac.nz/handle/10179/619'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I did some very basic benchmark and it turns out, I get results 40% faster using head than get: using the same payload, get takes 20 minutes, while head takes 12 minutes. This most certainly will help.